# How do I select elements when I already have a DOM element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery variable:

```
var $element = $(".element");
```

And I need another variable like:

```
var $visible = $(".element:visible");
```

Is it possible to combine these together? Means something like:

```
var $visible = $element:visible
```

Comment: No you can't...

Comment: Why would you? You have the combo in the `var $visible = $(".element:visible");`

Comment: @mplungjan in my case I have `var $a = $('.a')`, `var $b = $a.find('b')`, and now I want have something like `var $c = $b:visable`. In my case,  there are more level than this simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $visible = $element.filter(":visible").
```

See 'Additional Notes' [here](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for!